# What is the difference when create Set<T> in java

Tags: java, interfaces

When creating a Set in Java, what's the difference between the following? Which one should I use, and why?

```
Set< T > set = new HashSet<>();

HashSet< T > set = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site, but this question on stack overflow answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java

Comment: I can understand how it might appear off-topic, but I am not sure it really is.

Comment: @Snowman it is not really off topic but already answered at stackoverflow.

Comment: ...it was asked soooo many times

Comment: @TimothyTruckle that makes it neither off-topic nor a duplicate. Unless _our_ help center says it is off-topic, or there is a duplicate on _this_ site, it should be fine.

Comment: If anything this question should be closed as a duplicate of [Understanding “programming to an interface”](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/232359/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In object-oriented programming, there is a concept of "programming to an interface." The idea is you do not really care which type of set you use, only that it fulfills the contract of the `Set` interface (or `List`, or `Map`).

Your examples do not really show the benefits of the first example, but consider this code:

```
public class Example {
  public HashSet<String> doSomething() {
    final HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    // do stuff with the set
    return set;
  }
}
```

You use this class all over the place. There are tons of references, and code in multiple locations has to store the result of that method in a `HashSet<String>` reference.

Oops, now you have a requirements change, and order matters. `HashSet` does not guarantee iteration order, now you need a `TreeSet`. So you update the method to use `TreeSet`. Except now you have tons of references that need to be updated. Perhaps your IDE can update this for you: perhaps you have external users of the class and it will create headaches for them.

A better alternative is to *code to an interface*. Instead of defining the implementation in the method signature and body, use plain old `Set`. If the method's contract is that it returns an ordered set, return a `SortedSet`. If users of the set need not only order but there is also a guarantee that an iterator can navigate the set, return a `NavigableSet`.

```
public class Example {
  public SortedSet<String> doSomething() {
    final SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
    // do stuff with the set
    return set;
  }
}
```

The Java collections framework includes interfaces for most of the common implementations. The `Map` interface has subinterfaces mirroring the set interfaces I already mentioned (makes sense, because the sets delegate internally to maps). Lists are an exception (`ArrayList` implements `RandomAccess`, a marker interface), but queues (including `LinkedList`) have several interfaces.

Anyway, code to the highest level interface you can. If a consumer of your interface only wants to iterate, then store a reference to that set in a `Collection` or even `Iterable`, insulating it from interface changes later on.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Snowman is right for the general case. It is most of the time correct to code to an interface, for the reasons he stated.

There are cases however, where you don't want that, as the underlying implementation can make a big difference to performance.

Consider the case of a `List<E>` which you process by using `List.get(int)` and `List.set(int, E)`. While these operations are available for all `List` implementations, it will make a huge difference in performance whether you are working on an `ArrayList` or on a `LinkedList`.

In such a case you could define that your method accepts only `ArrayList` as a parameter. Or you could accept `List` and then create an `ArrayList` from it for processing.

So the answer is, it depends. In most cases code to an interface, but when you need to, don't be afraid to specify the exact type you are expecting.